# Image stats in Google Earth Engine and rgee package in R?

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I'm trying to calculate the mean of all pixels at the county level for an image in Google Earth Engine and am using the rgee package in R Studio.

I've tried following the example here: https://github.com/csaybar/rgee/blob/examples/image/image_stats_by_band.R

The code runs but results in a long print out in R of feature$geometry$coordinates, feature$properties, etc., and I just want the mean value of the band and would like to use the mean value in subsequent calculations. I think I want one of the value in one of the last lines that is printed: $features[[1]]$properties$data

```
#GY16 is an image covering a U.S. state with 1 band and I would like to calculate the mean of that image at the county level. shp1 is the county geometry.  

geometry <- shp1
means <- GY16$reduceRegions(
  collection = geometry,
  reducer = ee$Reducer$mean()$forEachBand(GY16),
  scale=10
)

print(means$getInfo())
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This example was made in rgee early versions, now you can use ee_extract:

```r
library(rgee)

# remotes::install_github("r-spatial/rgee") please install rgee v1.0.9
ee_Initialize()

image <- ee$Image("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ/m_3712213_sw_10_1_20140613")
geometry <- image$geometry()
ee_extract(image, geometry, scale = 100, sf = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried ee_extract but am receiving the following error: "Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Specify higher maxFeatures value if you intend to export a large area via getInfo.
Entered: 6101
maxFeatures:" Any ideas? Thank you for your help csaybar!